# aimless milling

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

"Prices in trading ranges go nowhere, just as crowds spend most of their time in aimless milling."

What does aimless milling mean here? I don't think it means its literal meaning.

Comment: _mill_ means _move around in a confused mass_. Why don't you think it means that?

Comment: It's usually used as part of the phrase _mill about_.

Comment: I know mill as milling grain e.g. wheat, oat, etc.

Comment: That's what dictionaries are for, to find the other definitions you didn't know.

Comment: @Barmar Wow, great remark. I wasn't aware of that! Pardon my ignorance. Seriously: I didn't find anything suitable in my dictionary of course.

Comment: Isn't it more like in "milling around"? https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1144&dat=19430612&id=yM8aAAAAIBAJ&sjid=oUwEAAAAIBAJ&pg=1502,3790316&hl=en

Comment: @Barmar OK, I found the right meaning. It's that what you said. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I just Googled "define mill".  Of the 6 dictionaries shown, only Macmillian lacked the definition needed (though it did link to "mill around").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's verb definition #3 of *mill* in [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mill):

> [NO OBJECT] (mill about/around) (Of people or animals) move around in a confused mass

Usually it's used with *about* or *around*, but this writer chose to leave this out, perhaps because it sounds clunky when used after a gerund.

*aimless* is used with its usual meaning, not having a purpose.

Comment: In summary the crowds are moving around in a confused mass without a clear objective.